# Inner join Giving columns Multiple values

Tags: sql-server, join

I have Three Tables In Database

**Table : Group**

> Id, Name

**Table : doctor**

> Id ,DId, DoctorName,

**Table : Ratio**

> Id , DId, UpLimit , downLimit.

When i inner join them , I am Getting duplicate Values to Uplimit and downlimit,,

Actually Group is related to doctors, One group id can have multple doctors,, so when i save some data with Group and doctor, it is saving to all the records with same data, uplimit downlimit varies with different doctors , but when i inner join dem its showing same to all doctors,, how to skip uplimit and downlimit how to write the Query..

```
Select A.Group , B.doctor , C.Uplimit, D.downlimit from Group A
inner join Doctor B
on A.id = B.id
inner join C ratio
on A.id = c.id
```

issue is When i separately check it with doctor id in doctor table it is showing only one record, when i inner join them its showing same data to all doctors to particular 
how to join them??

Comment: `C ratio` or `ratio C` ? Also there is no `D`

Comment: Ratio c , no d table

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `DISTINCT` clause after `SELECT`. This will filter the duplicates.

```
Select DISTINCT A.[Group] , B.doctor , C.Uplimit, D.downlimit 
FROM Group A
inner join Doctor B
on A.id = B.id
inner join Ratio C
on B.id = C.id
```

It is good to avoid using the keywords as table/column names.

Comment: @James, can you please post sample data and desired result?

Comment: Hey got my mistake, i was comparing the same id among three tables that was issue, now i modified the query in second inner join which gives my result,, thank you for responding

Answer (score 0):

You Table Structure must be like

**Table : Group**

> Id, Name

**Table : doctor**

> Id ,DId(foreign key for group table), DoctorName

**Table : Ratio**

> Id(Foreign Key for Doctor Table), UpLimit , downLimit.

Ratio Table is either missing a foreign key or a primary key, assuming Id of Ratio table is foreign key

```
Select A.Group , B.doctor , C.Uplimit, D.downlimit from Group A
inner join Doctor B
on A.id = B.Did
inner join ratio C
on B.id = c.id
```

This should give what you needed

Comment: No I think u didnt understand , Did is different  doctor id , different from id

Comment: Then what is the link between the tables? @James

Comment: id is the link , that is common in all tables..and table b and c have two columns common , did, did so i made a mistake in query which i got it now , now the query is working fine

Comment: Thanks for giving response